# Inserting a list in an IEnumerable of objects

Tags: c#

I have a IEnumerable 'myobjects' where myModel structure is as follows..

```
public class myModel
    {
        public string SchemaName { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public List<string> optionvalues { get; set; }
    }
```

In the above IEnumerable I have one myModel (lets say with SchemaName 'abc' and PropertyName 'xyz') where optionvalues is null(count=0).

I have a List 'mylist' which contains the values which needs to be inserted in the above IEnumerable in place of null optionvalues.

I would appreciate if someone could guide me how to insert mylist in myobjects where SchemaName is 'abc' and PropertyName is 'xyz' .

Thanks

Comment: You can't insert anything into `IEnumerable` since this interface doesn't contains any methods to do it. So you have to cast your object to concrete type implementing IEnumerable (if such underlying type exists)

Comment: You are doing a lot of "telling" instead of showing us code (such as the declaration/initialization of `myobjects`). Also, an `IEnumerable<myModel>` can be *enumerated over*, but otherwise cannot be added to.

Comment: You seem to have created two questions that seem to be remarkably similar. Do you have two questions or are you just unaware that you can [edit] your question to correct/respond? ([Other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506548/transforming-an-ienumerable-c-sharp))

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The two questions are diff..

Comment: please accept one of the answers given to you or explain whats wrong with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only single value (or you only want to add in the first occurred value) in `myobjects` which have that that schema name and property name You could do it this way:

```
var obj = myobjects.Single(x => 
    x.SchemaName =="abc" && x.PropertyName == "xyz" && (x.optionvalues == null || x.optionvalues.Count == 0));
obj.optionvalues = mylist;
```

or

```
var obj = myobjects.First(x => 
    x.SchemaName =="abc" && x.PropertyName == "xyz" && (x.optionvalues == null || x.optionvalues.Count == 0));
obj.optionvalues = mylist;
```

Alternatively, use `Where` and probably `ForEach`

```
var objcoll = myobjects.Where(x => 
    x.SchemaName =="abc" && x.PropertyName == "xyz" && (x.optionvalues == null || x.optionvalues.Count == 0)).ToList();
objcoll.ForEach(x => x.optionvalues = mylist);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = myobjects.Where(o=>o.SchemaName =="abc" && o.PropertyName == "xyz" && o.optionvalues==null);
foreach (var obj in filtered)
{
   obj.optionvalues=mylist;
}
```

note that in this implementation all your object will reference the same list, if you change something in mylist it will apply to all the objects using it.