# Transforming an IEnumerable C#

Tags: c#

I have a table 'Table1' whose structure is as follows..

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SchemaName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }
}
```

Using Entity Framework I can get the data out as an IEnumerable.

But I need the data as IEnumerable whose structure is as follows:

```
public class myschemaobj
{
    public string SchemaName { get; set; }
    public List<mypropobj> PropertyObjects { get; set; }        
}

public class mypropobj
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }
}
```

All help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need to group by `SchemaName`.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Table1.GroupBy(r=>r.SchemaName).Select(grp=>new myschemaobj
 {
  SchemaName = grp.Key,
  PropertyObjects = grp.Select(r=>new mypropobj
    {
      PropertyName = r.PropertyName,
      PropertyType = r.PropertyType
    })
  });
```

Comment: Suggest you add a bit more of an explanation to why this is the answer, not just the code.